# How to show number field with its format in Text formula field

Tags: formula, custom-object, formula-field

I have a field called "Annual Amount" and it is a number field. I am using this in an email quick action and I am returning this field in the email body where the return type is text. For the same, I am using `"$"&TEXT(Annual_Amount__c)`. The output is `$1000`.

Now, is there anyway I can display commas as well in the number when I use this function, which will be like `$1,000` instead of `$1000`.

Please suggest.

Comment: May i know, what is the reason for formula return type as text instead of number?

Comment: I am using this in an email quick action and I am returning this field in the email body where the return type is text

Comment: You can refer number fields also in email body. Just modify your formula return type as number and refer that field in email body

Comment: @AnkaiahBandi, the formula has both both text and number fields. Hence, to display numbers, I'm using the TEXT() function due to which the number format is going missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify your formula as like below.

```
    "$"&CASE(LEN(TEXT(Annual_Annual_Amount__c__c)),
```

1, TEXT(Annual_Amount__c),

2, TEXT(Annual_Amount__c),

3, TEXT(Annual_Amount__c),

4, LEFT(TEXT(Annual_Amount__c), 1) & "," & RIGHT(TEXT(Annual_Amount__c), 3),

5, LEFT(TEXT(Annual_Amount__c), 2) & "," & RIGHT(TEXT(Annual_Amount__c), 3),

6, LEFT(TEXT(Annual_Amount__c), 3) & "," & RIGHT(TEXT(Annual_Amount__c), 3),

7, LEFT(TEXT(Annual_Amount__c), 1) & "," & MID(TEXT(Annual_Amount__c), 2,3) & "," & RIGHT(TEXT(Annual_Amount__c), 3),

8, LEFT(TEXT(Annual_Amount__c), 2) & "," & MID(TEXT(Annual_Amount__c), 3,3) & "," & RIGHT(TEXT(Annual_Amount__c), 3),

9, LEFT(TEXT(Annual_Amount__c), 3) & "," & MID(TEXT(Annual_Amount__c), 4,3) & "," & RIGHT(TEXT(Annual_Amount__c), 3),

10, LEFT(TEXT(Annual_Amount__c), 1) & "," & MID(TEXT(Annual_Amount__c), 2,3) & "," & MID(TEXT(Annual_Amount__c), 5, 3) & "," & RIGHT(TEXT(Annual_Amount__c), 3),

11, LEFT(TEXT(Annual_Amount__c), 2) & "," & MID(TEXT(Annual_Amount__c), 3,3) & "," & MID(TEXT(Annual_Amount__c), 6, 3) & "," & RIGHT(TEXT(Annual_Amount__c), 3),

12, LEFT(TEXT(Annual_Amount__c), 3) & "," & MID(TEXT(Annual_Amount__c), 4,3) & "," & MID(TEXT(Annual_Amount__c), 7, 3) & "," & RIGHT(TEXT(Annual_Amount__c), 3),

null)

Answer (score 0):

TO USE: In a text formula field, enter the below code and replace units__c with the number field that you need displayed with commas. Note: If this output will be needed in several places, consider creating a custom formula field with just this code (e.g. unitsText__c) and use that field where needed to keep things nice & tidy.

```
/* Text Thousands Separator under 1 B - preserves decimals, negatives */
/* Under 1 K */
IF(units__c < 1000, TEXT(units__c),

/* Under 1 M */
IF(units__c < 1000000, TEXT(FLOOR(units__c /1000))
& ','
& RIGHT(TEXT(units__c), LEN(TEXT(units__c)) - LEN(TEXT(FLOOR(units__c /1000)))),

/* Under 1 B */
IF(units__c < 1000000000, TEXT(FLOOR(units__c /1000000))
& ','
& MID(TEXT(units__c), 1 + LEN(TEXT(FLOOR(units__c /1000000))),3)
& ','
& RIGHT(TEXT(units__c), LEN(TEXT(units__c)) - LEN(TEXT(FLOOR(units__c /1000)))),

/* 1 B & up */
IF(units__c >= 1000000000, "#TooHigh!", NULL))))
```